# linux-headers-3.16.0-4-amd64 vs. linux-headers-3.16-3-amd64

Tags: linux, debian, kernel

"uname -a" returns 3.16-3-amd64 as my kernel version but I could install 3.16.0-4 via synaptic.

Are these two same?

OS: Debian Jessie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer: NO! They are not the same. I assumed otherwise and faced lots of problems setting up virtualbox-dkms module. To resolve all these issues I upgraded my kernel to 3.16.0-4-amd64 for which there were appropriate Linux headers.